# Javascript: str-replace special characters

Tags: javascript, str-replace

i have some script that is generating different color for letters or numbers when you enter some special character.
Example: ^1 = red ^2 = green ^3 = yellow

Its working when i enter for example ^1name. then the name is getting red. The problem is when i enter numbers. For example "^1na3me". Then im getting "na" in red color and "me" in yellow color. But it should be "na3me" in only red. It should only takes the colors when the number getting entered with a ^ before it. Somebody knows why this happen?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$(".word").keyup(function()
{
var word=$(this).val();
$(".word_preview").html(word);
return false;
});
});
</script>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/[^]0/g, '<span style="color:black">').replace(/[^]1/g, '<span style="color:red">').replace(/[^]2/g, '<span style="color:green">').replace(/[^]3/g, '<span style="color:yellow">').replace(/[^]4/g, '<span style="color:blue">').replace(/[^]5/g, '<span style="color:cyan">').replace(/[^]6/g, '<span style="color:#D02090">').replace(/[^]7/g, '<span style="color:white">');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter name:
         <br/>
         <input type="text" name="maprotation" size="50" id="textfield"  class="word" class="Stil69">
         <input type="reset" name="Submit3" value="Reset" />
          <br/><br/>
         <h3>2. Click the button to preview your colored name.</h3>
         <br/>
         <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click here"/>
         <br/><br/>
         <table bgcolor="#333333"><tr><td><span class="word_preview" id="demo"><td></span></tr></table>
         <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never close the span so it does not make much sense.... Do you know what `[^]` actually does in a regular expression? [MDN reg exp character sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets)

Comment: it's because `[^]` is empty negative list of characters you need to escape `^` with `\^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your regex is wrong. `[^]` mean any character that is listed (except `^`). You need to escape it like `/\^0/`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = $("#demo").text();
  var res = str
    .replace(/\^0(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:black">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^1(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:red">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^2(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:green">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^3(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:yellow">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^4(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:blue">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^5(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:cyan">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^6(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:#D02090">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\^7(\w+)/g, '<span style="color:white">$1</span>')
  ;

  $("#demo").html(res);
};

$(function() {
  $(".word").keyup(function() {
    $(".word_preview").html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


Enter name:
<br/>
<input type="text" name="maprotation" size="50" id="textfield" class="word" class="Stil69">
<input type="reset" name="Submit3" value="Reset" />
<br/>
<br/>
<h3>2. Click the button to preview your colored name.</h3>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click here" />
<br/>
<br/>
<table bgcolor="#333333">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="word_preview" id="demo"><td></span>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
```

Comment: ok i got it. when i enter a name like ^1john^doe^  then the ^doe^ is getting black, but it should be red.

Comment: @hansfrans For that regex would be something like `\^1(.*)`. I can't write best regex as you did not specify detailed rules for entered string

Comment: If entered only a ^ then the color shouldnt change.